# Getting cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAnimatePolicy') in extjs 7.5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs7

I have my component that `extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel'` and when I add that to my container using `container.add(createView)` where createView is the component thats extending Ext.tab.panel it throws error `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAnimatePolicy')`. It works fine in other cases but in the one where we extend: Ext.tab.panel. Extjs have removed this method from Ext.tab.Panel but since my way of adding the view in container is generic It throws this error.

I'm using extjs 7.5 version if you guys have any change that you can recommend that would be very helpful

Comment: Please create a Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate your issue. Without the code it is really hard to help.

Comment: Following is the fiddle I have found which was facing the same issue:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m03&view/editor
If you click on "Add new Tab" it will throw that error

Comment: This error comes from the loading mask in the fiddle you linked, do you use load mask as well?

Comment: yes I use that as well

Comment: It was working fine for me on extjs 4.1 but after upgrading it to 7.5 this issue came. So if there any config should I do or set some prop let me know about it

Comment: This is a huge jump, from 4 to 7, there were a lot of braking changes. The fiddle you linked is on version 5. If you can set up your own fiddle in 7.5 I can have a look.

Comment: Its difficult to set that up. If you can provide the solution in this issue. I think I would be able solve it in my work as well

Comment: @PeterKoltai any resolution on this if you can provide

Comment: Sorry, I can't. If you can create a fiddle I can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am sorry for my poor English.
A looked at your code, you have some mistakes:

You use Ext.create to create a panel component, and trying to remove it in button's handler. After you call `tabpanel.removeAll()` this component become deleted and don't exist anymore. Don't use `Ext.create`, method `add()` should have config object

```
    var panel = {
          xtype: 'panel',
          title: 'Test'
    };
    //...
    handler: function() { 
    //... 
        tabpanel.add(panel);
    }
```

Try to DO NOT use `Ext.getCmp` and 'id' property, you can navigate from component to component by using `up()` and `down()` methods or view's `references` with `this.lookup('refName')` in controller.

Also you can use `component.setLoading('Waiting...')` to show mask and `.setLoading(false)` to hide it instead of `Ext.getCmp('mask')` or etc.